# How would you limit file size created by a python subprocess?

Tags: python

I run a subprocess from python like this (not my script):

```
  with contextlib.redirect_stdout(log_file):
    # ....
    processResult = subprocess.run(args, 
                    stdout=sys.stdout, 
                    stderr=sys.stderr
                    timeout=3600)
```

and sometimes the process goes crazy (due to an intermittent bug) and dumps so many errors into the stdout/logfile so that it grows to 40Gb and fills up the disk space.

What would be the best way to protect against that? Being a python newbie, I have 2 ideas:

- piping the subprocess into something like `head` that aborts it if output grows beyond limit (not sure if this is possible with subprocess.run or do I have to go the low level Popen way)
- finding or creating some handy IO wrapper class IOLimiter which would throw an error after a given size (couldn't find anything like this in stdlib and not even sure where to look for it)

I suspect there would be some smarter/cleaner way?

Comment: Try adding logging with https://stackoverflow.com/a/24505345/6529424

Answer (score 2):

I recently had [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53965917/streaming-read-from-subprocess) myself.  I did it with the `popen` method, setting `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`

```
test_proc = subprocess.Popen(
    my_command,
    universal_newlines=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
)

print(time.time(), "START")
# Iterate over the lines of output produced
for out_data in iter(test_proc.stdout.readline, ""):
    # Check whatever I need.
```

Comment: Thanks.. I was hoping not having to change to use Popen - but this deosn't look bad - but I guess you'd have think about killing the process, also timeouts, etc (and whatever run() is doing). My other concern would be performance - forgot to mention this file ends up being 40G - so would prefer some optimised processing rather than a python loop.. or should I not  worry about it?  updating the question anyway with clarifications.

Comment: Yes, depending on your application, there are various considerations to the interaction.  This one at least gives you a non-blocking situation and a reasonably efficient loop: remember, this is one end of a pipe, so the loop iterates *only* when the child process writes a line.  Otherwise, the parent process is simply waiting.